# how to set click listener in TextField flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

how we can set click listener in TextField dart language for android application. I have used the following code.But its not working now

```
 Container(
                                child: GestureDetector(
                              child: new IgnorePointer(
                                child: TextField(
                                  focusNode: _focus,
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  controller: billDateFromController,
                                ),
                              ),
                              onTap: () {
                                showDatePickerData(context);
                              },
                            )),
```

Comment: The `TextField` has an `onTap` property. What else are you looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

To enable click listener on TextField use `onTapDown` of `GestureDetector`